# how t split the contents of a dataframe columns with Nan values in it? (note: I cannot drop the Nan rows)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, set

| Fruits |
| --- |
| Home>Fruits>mango |
|  |
| Home>Fruits>apple |

Expected output:

| Fruits | fruits split |
| --- | --- |
| Home>Fruits>mango | [Home,Fruits, Mango] |
|  |  |
| Home>Fruits>apple | [Home,Fruits, Apple] |

def spilt(a):
return re.split(pattern = r"[>]", string = a)

I'm trying this but it is giving **TypeError** Expected string or buffer error

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) if dont need capitalize strings:

```
df['fruits split'] = df['Fruits'].str.split('>')
print (df)
              Fruits           fruits split
0  Home>Fruits>mango  [Home, Fruits, mango]
1                NaN                    NaN
2  Home>Fruits>apple  [Home, Fruits, apple]
```

Solutions with [`title/capitalize`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59384880/any-difference-between-str-capitalize-and-str-title) each value of lists:

```
df['fruits split'] = df['Fruits'].str.split('>')
                                 .apply(lambda x: np.nan if isinstance(x, float) 
                                                    else [y.title() for y in x])
```

---

```
df['fruits split'] = [np.nan if isinstance(x, float) 
                      else [y.title() for y in x.split('>')]
                      for x in df['Fruits']]
```

---

```
df['fruits split'] = [np.nan if isinstance(x, float) else [y.title() for y in x] 
                      for x in df['Fruits'].str.split('>')]
print (df)
              Fruits           fruits split
0  Home>Fruits>mango  [Home, Fruits, Mango]
1                NaN                    NaN
2  Home>Fruits>apple  [Home, Fruits, Apple]
```

Comment: what about the nan values in between the rows?

Comment: nothing, just skip and continue to split others

Comment: @pheonix - I think solutions in answer shoud working well.